# SUBSTRING QUERY with update

Tags: sql, sql-server

Struggling with the following. 
Below is a screen shot when I run the following query -

```
select [Journal Source], [File], filepath from xIntegration..FinanceIntegration WHERE FilePath like '%rent debit%'
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is update Journal Source with the first number before the _ (underscore) of the field File.

The issue when I run the below code it is setting the Journal Source to 9 for all rows and not just where I would expect.

I would expect that the first 4 rows would change to 8 and the remaining change to 9.

```
--UPDATE THE BATCH NUMBER (Journal Source) For Rent Debit File
DECLARE @filenameRentDebit as varchar(100)
SELECT @filenameRentDebit =  [File] FROM FinanceIntegration WHERE FilePath like '%rent debit%'

DECLARE @indexRentDebit INT 
set @indexRentDebit = CHARINDEX('_', @filenameRentDebit)

UPDATE FinanceIntegration
SET [Journal Source] = SUBSTRING(@filenameRentDebit, 0, @indexRentDebit) 
WHERE FilePath like '%rent debit%'
```

What stupid mistake am i making? Thanks

Comment: This looks like SQL Server so I added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right idea, except for using variables.  You want:

```
UPDATE FinanceIntegration
    SET [Journal Source] = SUBSTRING([File], 0, CHARINDEX('_', [File])) 
    WHERE FilePath like '%rent debit%';
```

A variable has a single value, coming from an arbitrary row of the table.

Comment: Could also use `LEFT([File], CHARINDEX('_', [File]) - 1)` since the value he wants is always on the left side.

Comment: Thank you all so much!! Of course a variable can only hold one value :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd update with a combination of `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` and `CAST`:

```
UPDATE xIntegration..FinanceIntegration
SET [Journal Source] = CAST(SUBSTRING([File], 1, CHARINDEX('_', [File]) - 1) as INT)
WHERE FilePath like '%rent debit%'
```

Explanation:

- `CHARINDEX('_', [File])` finds the index of the first underscore character.
- `SUBSTRING([FILE], 1, CHARINDEX(...) - 1)` cuts the right part
- optionally, you might need to cast this to `INT` if `[Journal Source]` is `INT` too.